# Django_tables2 ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not str

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am rendering `django_tables2` table in a template using the `{% render_table table %}` tag, but I am getting the error:

```
localserver error:
Internal Server Error: /keymanager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\IENG_MIS\views.py", line 29, in issuekey
    return render(request, 'keymanagement.html', {'form': form})
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\mis_env\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\templatetags\django_tables2.py", line 144, in render
    raise ValueError("Expected table or queryset, not {}".format(klass))
ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not str
[16/Oct/2019 22:42:32] "GET /keymanager HTTP/1.1" 500 117360
```

models.py

K

tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import issuekeys

class issued_table(tables.Table):
    model=issuekeys
    template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"

    fields=('keynumber', 'workorder','contrator','assigned_name','assigned_contact','date_to_return',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from .forms import issuekeyform
from .tables import issued_table
from .models import issuekeys



@login_required()
def landing_page(request):
        return render(request, 'landing_page.html')
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
def issuekey(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        global form
        form= issuekeyform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)

            post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/keymanager')
    else:
            form = issuekeyform()

    return render(request, 'keymanagement.html', {'form': form})



def issuetable():
     table = issued_table(issuekeys.objects.all())
     RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 10}).configure(table)
     return render(request, "keymanagement.html", {'table': table})
```

kemanagement.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<div class="col-4">
                <h4 class="text-primary" style="text-align:left; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif" >Register Key:</h4>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em; margin-left: 1mm">
                    {% render_table table %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am using:

```
django_tables2 version: 2.1.1
django version: 2.2.6
```

Comment: Can you include the full error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

The error stacktrace shows this somewhere in the middle:

```
...
  File "C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\source\repos\management_information_system\management_information_system\IENG_MIS\views.py", line 29, in issuekey
    return render(request, 'keymanagement.html', {'form': form})
...
```

Notice how it refers to the function `issuekey`, but in your views you showed only the function `issuetable`.

So you either showed a different view function or you accidentally showed a different error stacktrace, because these 2 don't belong together.

Could you update your view or your error stacktrace, so we can help you further?

Comment: i omitted the function dealing with a form. kindly check